# Declaring a dictionary in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, dictionary

I'm getting an error `Run-time error '424': Object required` when I try to create a dictionary in VBA. My code is shown below:

```
Private Sub data()
Dim dicti As Object
Set dicti = CreateObject(Scripting.Dictionary)
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Is it possible that it is not allowed to post certain links as I did in my first comment which is gone?

Comment: @Storax hmm not sure why that happened

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try,

```
dim dicti As Object
Set dicti = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
```

Alternately, swap the late binding for early binding by accessing the VBE's Tools, References and including Microsoft Scripting Runtime with a check.

```
dim dicti as new Scripting.Dictionary
```

[image]

Comment: Early binding is great to get your intellisense options

Comment: It is faster and also makes an additional looping method available. I'd have to check but I think it is `for i=0 to dict.count-1: debug.print dict.keys(i)`

Comment: You do an incremental loop over the keys or Items of a late bound dictionary by accessing the keys array `Dictionary.Keys()(x)` or .`Dictionary.Items()(x)` .