# dictionarys and functions: User-defined type not defined

Tags: excel, function, dictionary, vba

I have typed the following code in Excel VBA:
The function should create a dictionary acording to unique values in a certain column part.

```
Function CreateDictForFactors(xcord As Integer, ycord As Integer, length As Integer) As Dictionary
Dim Dict As Dictionary
Set Dict = New Dictionary
Dim i As Integer
For i = 0 To length - 1
If Not Dict.Exists(Cells(xcord + i, ycord)) Then
            Dict.Add Cells(xcord + i, ycord), 0
            End If
Next i
Set CreateDictForFactors = Dict
End Function

Sub test2()
Dim dict1 As Dictionary
Set dict1 = CreateDictForFactors(7, 6, 12)

End Sub
```

I found this code as an excample for dictionaries and functions:

```
Sub mySub()
    dim myDict as Dictionary
    set myDict = myFunc()
End Sub

Function myFunc() as Dictionary
    dim myDict2 as Dictionary
    set myDict2 = new Dictionary
            'some code that does things and adds to myDict2'
    set myFunc=myDict2
End Function
```

However when I try to run the makro `test2` it gives the error message:

> User-defined type not defined

Can anyone tell where I made a mistake?
Thank you in advance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51233284/declaring-a-dictionary-in-vba#comment89450438_51233284

Answer (score 0):

G'day,

Did you add "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" as a reference to your project?

Once you've done that, declare dict as a Scripting.Dictionary like this:

```
Dim dict As Scripting.Dictionary
```

You can create the object as follows:

```
Set dict = New Scripting.Dictionary
```

This is a good website describing the use of a dictionary:

https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-dictionary/

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can also late bind the code like this:

```
Function CreateDictForFactors(xcord As Integer, ycord As Integer, length As Integer) As Dictionary
Dim Dict As Object
Set Dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Dim i As Integer
For i = 0 To length - 1
If Not Dict.Exists(Cells(xcord + i, ycord)) Then
            Dict.Add Cells(xcord + i, ycord), 0
            End If
Next i
Set CreateDictForFactors = Dict
End Function

Sub test2()
Dim dict1 As Object
Set dict1 = CreateDictForFactors(7, 6, 12)

End Sub
```

Note that neither method will work on a Mac.